# Definition of an even or odd function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition, even-and-odd-functions

I am a little confused about the definition of an odd function and an even function. The additive inverse part is clear but my question is does the function have to be univariate?
Does it have to be from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?
Any help in this direction would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about the univariate part. But as for the function,  the definition is $$\forall{x, -x\in \mathcal{D}(f)}:\ f(x)=f(-x)$$ for an even function and likewise for an odd function. (Note, $\mathcal{D}(f)$ denotes the domain of $f$.)

Comment: If $-x,-f(x)$ are defined, then you can define even/odd functions.

Comment: For a function, say $f\colon\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$, one way to define an odd function would be $f(-\mathbf x)=-f(\mathbf x)$ where $\mathbf x\in\Bbb R^m$. Another way could be to define in terms of the components: $f$ is odd wrt $x_i$ iff $f(x_1,\ldots,-x_i,\ldots,x_m)=-f(x_1,\ldots,x_i,\ldots,x_m)$. I think the former would be the usual definition, but the latter one could also be used. Depends on the author.

Comment: @Sayantan: As comments and answers are suggesting, context can be key here. Please state in full "the definition" that you have.

Answer (score 1):

With multivariate functions, oddness/eveness is general talked about in respect to a specific variable. $f(x,y)$ is odd with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with multivariable functions there is a generalisation of parity. So, a single variable function, call it f(x), is even if f(x)=f(-x) for every value of x in the domain. f(x) is called even if f(x)=-f(-x). Now, with multivariable functions there is a generalisation of parity, as I said at the start. Here though functions aren't called even or odd: they are called even symmetric or odd symmetric. A multivariable function, call it f(x_1, x_2,x_3,...,x_n) (where x_n is x sub n), is even symmetric if f(x_1, x_2,x_3,...,x_n)=f(-x_1, -x_2,x_3,...,-x_n).
f(x_1, x_2,x_3,...,x_n) is called odd symmetric if f(x_1, x_2,x_3,...,x_n)f(-x_1, -x_2,x_3,...,-x_n). As in the single variable world, the only function that is odd and even is f(x_1, x_2,x_3,...,x_n)=0. As in the single variable world, there are functions which are neither odd nor even.